# Display view content before template rendering

Tags: ember.js

I have a model which has a `belongsTo` field, but that field is not getting initialized. I would like to see the full object content (on the javascript console) right before the template accesses the view / controller.

Is it possible to tell ember to dump the view / controller values on the console, for all objects being rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Probably the fastest thing to do is use handlebars `{{log}}` helper. It will log the value of a specified object to console during render:

```
{{log this}}
```

If debugging a specific ember-data model, you might also consider enabling logging state manager transitions on it:

```
record.set("stateManager.enableLogging", true)
```

Comment: This works, thanks! And now I am even more confused since, as expected, my `belongsTo` field is initialized with the correct values, but the template is not able to render those values. I am using the syntax `{{properties.email}}` to access a subfield of the `belongsTo` field (`properties`)

Comment: what happens if you `{{log properties}}` and `{{log properties.email}}`. Also you might try writing a few objects directly to the template like: `<pre>this: {{this}}` properties: `{{properties}}</pre>` - ember will call `toString()` on them, see if they are really the objects you expected.

Comment: Properties is indeed `null`, no matter how I log it (either with `log` or `<pre>`). `this` is fine. I was wrong in my previous comment: I can not say anymore that `properties` is initialized with the right values (I think I took a look at the json received from the server instead of the `{{log this}}` - how to prefix the log with text, to avoid confussion? can I do `{{log "Hello" this}}`? I think not). So properties is indeed empty, even though the json is correct. The interesting thing is that another model reusing the same `properties` (also with `belongsTo`) has no trouble at all.

Comment: Found it! I was missing `properties: {embedded: 'always'}` in the new map. Thanks @intuitivepixel!

Answer (score 3):

What you might also beeing able to do, is to listen to your record's `didLoad` event. This will be fired when all the record data has beeing fetched from the backend (even `belongsTo` relations assuming you have defined the relations with `{embedded: 'always'}`):

```
record.on('didLoad', function() {
  console.log(record);
});
```

> **Note from the docs:** A record that is both loaded and clean means that is has received information about its attributes and relationships from the server, and no changes have been made locally on the client.

But for debugging purposes only Mike Grassotti's answer is also a good option.

Hope it helps